# Power of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

We have proved that if $a > 3$, then $a$, $a+ 2$, and $a+ 4$ cannot be all primes in previous question. Can we say that 
they all be powers of primes?

Comment: No. Take $a=4$, then $a$ and $a+4$ are powers of $2$, but $a+2 = 6$, which is not a prime power.

Comment: @A.D. Please stop using the tag *theorem provers* for this sort of question. Read what this tag is for [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/theorem-provers/info).

Comment: @ah11950 the OP is not looking for a counter example, but asking if it is possible at all.

Comment: @Hayden to me "can we say that...?" means "can we say that...is true [in generality]"? My misunderstanding...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have requested *Exponential diophantine equations* by T.N. Shorey and R. Tijdeman from a nearby library as i am now curious.

In case the requirement is for all exponents larger than one, we can probably find all solutions (likely none). The point is that one of the numbers is divisible by 3, therefore is $3^k.$ With unknown primes $p,q,r,s,$ exponents $t,u,v,w \geq 2,$ we want all solutions to
$$ 3^k + 2 = p^t,  $$ 
$$ 3^k + 4 = q^u,  $$
$$ 3^k - 2 = r^v,  $$
$$ 3^k - 4 = s^w.  $$
My guess is that, because of the fixed 3, these four can be solved individually.

Komputer Kalkulation: I just ran it up to $3^{20} \pm 2,4,$ all I found was $27 - 2 = 25.$ I suspect that is all...

Note that replacing the fixed $3$ by another unknown prime [leads to open problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tijdeman%27s_theorem).

Comment: I was looking for some good references - ++1 for signposting good material.

Comment: @MarkBennet, thanks. I believe I missed the significance of something, though. Since one of two consecutive numbers is even, the Catalan Conjecture was always about $2^n - p^k = \pm 1,$ and was quite difficult. So, my four problems above may well be unknown.

Answer (score 3):

If you count first powers as powers of primes, you have $5,7,9$ and $7,9,11$ and $9,11,13$ and $23, 25, 27$ and $25,27,29$.

You can't have even numbers, and one will be a multiple of $3$, so will have to be a power of $3$, and this reduces the search space somewhat. $79, 81, 83$ is the next example.

I've no idea about the distribution of such things through.

Comment: You forgot $27,29,31$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thinking and writing too quickly!